# ng-class opposite conditions are not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I literally have this in my code:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'green' : flag, 'red' : !flag }">
  {{flag}}
</div>
```

And it compiles into `<div class="red green">true</div>`

I cannot reproduce it in codepen or jsbin, this is some black magic right here because yesterday it worked fine and I haven't touched it. I hope somebody here could share an idea why could this be happening because I'm completely stuck on this. When I remove either of the two conditions, the remaining one works properly — setting the correct class depending on flag value.

**UPDATE**: All the suggestions about ternary operand will not help me as I have complex conditions in the real situation, but it all boils down to that single opposite Boolean variable difference. I've strapped the difference to just 2 conditions and with just that Boolean variable and it still didn't work. And that stripped down code is what I've posted.

Comment: What is the value of the `flag` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the place where the flag is being set to true into $timeout and it started working. However I still cannot understand, if that was a scope digest issue, how come it did display **true** on the page and why both conditions were met. Some quantum mechanics double-slit s**t right there.

Answer (score 1):

Make it conditionally like :

```
<div ng-class="(flag) ? 'green' : 'red'">
```

Or

```
<div ng-class="{true:'green', false:'red'}[flag]"></div>
```

Please indicate if this solves the problem, since these are just other ways of using the `ng-class` directive.

If the problem still occures, can you specify the value of `flag`. Is it undefined? Is it a boolean? ...

Comment: Yes 100% correct. He should try if that makes any difference. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{flag ? 'green' : 'red'}">
```

Comment: what OP is trying should have work.. this is other way of doing the same...

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this

```
<div ng-class="flag ? 'green' : 'red'">
```